# GitHUB rejected master -> master (non-fast-forward)

Tags: github, egit

This might be recursive and i have seen answers about this questions on other thread here on Stackoverflow.

The reason i am asking is that i dont understand one thing, that when it gives this error, i have seen answers here that tell that it is because that the remote master on Github is no where in my history of master branch on my local repository that is why it gives this error.

I have also seen explanations where it is written that the changes on remote have to be merged locally and then push your changes from local to remote.

So what i have done is that i have created a remote repository on github and am trying to push my changes from eclipse to this remote repository and it throws me this error. Regarding second solution of merging the changes first from remote, but i dont have anything to merge it is a new repository. So why does it throw this error.

Comment: Run `git fetch` then `git log origin/master --not master` and you'll see the difference between the remote master and your local master. Add the output here and we might be able to help better.

Comment: warning: no common commits    remote: Counting Objects: 3 done  Remote: Total 3  Unpacking objects: 100% 3/3 From https://github.com/araza/tob  *[new branch]  master  -> RemoteName/master

Answer (score 0):

This particular error is because the Local Branch is not up to date in order to Push your commit(The remote branch is updated with other commits).

Fetch from the Upstream to sync your Local Branch and the Remote Branch

Pull the changes

Then Push your commits which will be fast forward without any conflicts